# Converting Zulu time to local time in java

Tags: java, api, github

I'm trying to work with the github api, but according to the test api endpoint I was given to try, all of the times are in zulu time, and I need to convert them to a local timezone, and after a brief scouring of the internet, I can't find any easy way to do so.

Github endpoint in question: https://api.github.com/repos/izuzak/pmrpc/commits?path=README.markdown

Example Timestamp: `2014-01-03T17:41:23Z`

Comment: @gulmer OP says "in java"

Comment: What version of Java? It's built in to 8.

Comment: relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date

Comment: @hd1 - Doh! The strategy is: 1) use a function to parse the time string, represented in a well understood format like  ISO 8601, and convert that into a 'universal' form, seconds from a fixed, known, point (e.g. start of epoch for UNIX is 1st of January 1970, 00:00:00). Then 2) use a function to build a string (again in  ISO 8601 or similar) for the local time zone.

Comment: See my answer, please?

Comment: @chrylis it's built-in to Java, since version 1.1, but it's always a buggy implementation. Hence, the good Lord gave us joda.

Comment: @hd1.4 You seem a bit out of date. Java 8 overhauled time handling, largely inspired by Joda.

Answer (score 0):

```
String time = "2014-01-03T17:41:23Z";
DateTimeFormatter format = ISODateTimeFormat.basicDateTime();
DateTime jodaObj = format.parseDateTime(time);
```

If you use [joda](http://www.joda.org/joda-time), the above should sort you.